# RegEx: find multiple appearance of one group within a RegEx with a second group and boundaries

Tags: javascript, regex

As example:

```
foo for 2019:

month value
    3   101
    4   202
    5   303

bar for xyz
```

Is is possible to get all months and the year by only one regex rule?

To get the last month I would use:
`/foo\sfor\s(?<year>20\d\d)[^]+\n+\s*(?<month>\d+)\s[^]+bar\sfor/gm`

Target platform: nodeJS

Comment: No, you can't do it with one regex match operation. Capture the text with the month data (e.g. `/foo\sfor\s(20\d\d):([^]+)bar\sfor/`) and then run `capture_group_2_text.match(/\d+(?=[ \t]+\d)/gm)` on it.

Comment: `[^]+` = `[\s\S]+` "give me all" (works in JS and on RegEx101)

Comment: Hmm, ok. It could be a problem with unnamed groups. My solution would be a array return instead of a string. But it would be complicated to implement these in all languages (like static type languages).

Comment: What do you mean by "in all languages"? Is it not a JS question?

Comment: It is a specific problem for JS, but I see RegEx as a common standard with little language specific rulesets.

Comment: Then please pay attention to the [regex tag details](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.* It is not a "common standard" and has never been. Each regex should be tailored for the environment where it is going to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with one regex match operation. You need to first get the year with one capturing group and then capture all text with all month data into Group 2, and then run another regex on Group 2 value only to grab all the month numbers separately.

You may use

```js
var text = "foo for 2019:\n\nmonth value\n    3   101\n    4   202\n    5   303\n\nbar for xyz";
var match = /foo\sfor\s(20\d\d):([^]+?)bar\sfor/.exec(text);
if (match) {
    console.log("Year: ", match[1]);
    var months = match[2].match(/\d+(?=[ \t]+\d)/gm);
    console.log("Months: ", months);
}
```